# Restore root site collection using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, restore

I have a Web App with a root and four different HNSCs. I've been able to successfully backup and restore the HNSCs from a dev environment, but I am having trouble achieving this with my root site collection.

This is my PowerShell script:

```
Restore-SPSite http://contoso.com/ -Path xxx.bak -DatabaseServer xxx -DatabaseName xxx -HostHeaderWebApplication http://contoso.com -Force
```

I get the following error:

```
Restore-SPSite : The URL 'http://contoso.com/' is in use as an alternate access URL or as the URL of a host header site.  Please choose a different URL and try again.
```

I tried removing the existing root site collection before running the script with the same outcome. I even tried using / as the Site Collection's url with no success.

[Microsoft examples](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx) are for site collections under sites, not root site collections. So, is this even possible?

Comment: Is root level site collection is hnsc? If you go central admin> view all site collections under the Web app check what is the url of "/" site collection

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Same as the Web App's url: http:// contoso.com

Comment: Try to run the command without host header parameter?

Comment: Great, I added that into as answer for other benifit as well as for some rewards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to restore a site collection, I would remove the host headerwebapplication url from coomand i.e

```
Restore-SPSite http://contoso.com/ -Path xxx.bak -DatabaseServer xxx -DatabaseName xxx  -Force
```

Comment: Great, It works. Thanks a lot!